# Date formatting not working in Swift 3

Tags: nsdateformatter, swift3

I'm having a problem with NSDate in a function. Essentially, the formatting is not working, and I need another set of eyes to see what I'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var dateField: NSTextField!

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd yyyy"
let currentDate = NSDate()

convertedDateString = dateFormatter.string(from:currentDate as Date)
dateField.stringValue = convertedDateString as String

print("convertedDate: ", convertedDateString)
print("dateField.stringValue: ", dateField.stringValue)
```

Result:

> convertedDate:  July 25 2016
>   dateField.stringValue:  7/25/16

Comment: according to this site everything is ok http://nsdateformatter.com/

Comment: what's your dateField? The formatter seems right.

Comment: The date field (whatever that is) probably requires some specific format.

Comment: the dateField is described as `  @IBOutlet weak var dateField: NSTextField!` the date is the current date

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
Date().toString() // convert date to string with userdefined format.

extension Date {
        func toString() -> String {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd yyyy"
            return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks great. I've tried in a demo and it seems to work. I'll try in my project, but I'll mark this as a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Also you can do the same for NSDate via
`NSDate().toString()` and
`extension NSDate {...}`

Answer (score 8):

Extension for getting string against date formats

```
extension Date {
        func toString(format: String) -> String {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
            return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
        }
    }

Date().toString(format:"H:mm")
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what i try on the playground and it works.

```
import Foundation

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd yyyy"
let currentDate = NSDate()

let convertedDateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
var dateField:NSTextField = NSTextField()
dateField.stringValue = convertedDateString as String

print(convertedDateString) //July 25 2016
print(dateField.stringValue) //July 25 2016
```

The only different was that i change to `NSDateFormatter` and instead of `dateFormatter.string` i have `dateFormatter.stringFromDate`.

[image]

Did you accidentally set some value in the storyboard or xib that you have the `NSTextField`?

Comment: Hi, in your playground, the dateField is a string, not  an NSTextField

Comment: Okay, i updated the playground for OSX and also the dateField to NSTextField. It still work.

Comment: the dateFormatter.string(from:currentDate as Date) is Swift 3. I appreciate you help though

Comment: I ran the same in the playground, and get an error. Might be a bug.

Comment: Oh, saw the updated question now. It look like a bug, maybe you should file a report.

Answer (score 0):

The issue i had was not deleting the App from my phone before re installing and testing. The code was working in the simulator but not the phone. Hope this helps